# redux-form and react widgets' calendar - invalid prop value of type String

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I want to use react-widgets calendar as input for start date and end date,
simplest implementation works:

```
const TripValidationForm = React.createClass({


FormDatepicker : ({input}) => {
    return (<Calendar {...input} /> );
},
onSubmit : function(formData) {
  const uid = this.props.auth.uid;
    this.props.createTrip(formData, uid);
},
render : function() {
    const {handleSubmit, submitting, feedback} = this.props;
return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)} className="form-home">
            <fieldset>
                <Field name="startdate" valueField="value" component={this.FormDatepicker} />
                <Field name="enddate" valueField="value" component={this.FormDatepicker}/>
            </fieldset>
            <p className="error">{feedback.msg}</p>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-black" disabled={submitting}>Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
);
}
});
```

However following errors pop in my console, how I can prevent them from showing up?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, docs for a calendar widget say

> The current selected date, should be a Date object or null.

So I used solution from one redux-form git-hub issues for datepicker

```
FormDatepicker : ({input}) => {
    const selected = input.value ? new Date(input.value) : null;
    return (<Calendar {...input} value={selected}  /> );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like the warnings are coming from the props validation on the react widget calendar source, not much you can do unless you want to modify the source. Also this warnings are only shown in dev mode, if you bundle your code for production you shouldn't see any of this warnings